# javascript reduce not working - trying to sum multiple object values inside array

Tags: javascript, reduce

There are many objects inside games array, I want to return the object inside reduce function with all the calculations. Current code is working fine with two array items only.

```js
games = [
    { 
     game_id: 21700001,
     pts: 27},
    {
     game_id: 21700002,
     pts: 27
    },
    {
     game_id: 21700002,
     pts: 27

    }]
    
    

var stats = games.reduce(function(prev, curr) {

return { ppg: prev.pts + curr.pts }

});


console.log(stats);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a universal debugger. Please provide some additional information. At least: what is the current behavior? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: currently, reducer functions summing the pts of prev and curr objects. reducer function should be able to sum object values for all the objects inside an array. the current code is only working when there are two objects inside array but should be working for any number of objects.

Comment: Put together a simplified test case. It should be trivial to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an initial argument to reduce -

```
.reduce(function(prev,curr) {
...
},{});
```

AND THEN, if it's your first pass through, then you have to understand that `prev.XXX` will be undefined, so you can always chalk it up to a 0:

```
return { 
    ppg: ((prev.pts || 0) + curr.pts)/totalGames, 
    apg: ((prev.ast || 0) + curr.ast)/totalGames, 
    rpg: ((prev.oreb || 0) + curr.oreb + (prev.dreb || 0) + curr.dreb)/totalGames, 
    fgp: (((prev.fgm || 0) + curr.fgm)/((prev.fga || 0) + curr.fga))*100, 
    fg3p: (((prev.fg3m || 0) + curr.fg3m)/((prev.fg3a || 0) + curr.fg3a))*100 
}
```

And if it still fails - then check your console for errors.

Comment: @TKG what is not working? Is your array elements have the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce uses the thing that you return as `prev`.
Ergo, if you return a `string` from `reduce`, then the value of `prev` is a string. If you return an object that is nothing like the previous object, then you aren't going to be adding two of the same kind together.

Break this into multiple parts.

```
const tallyGames = (a, b) =>
  Object.assign({}, a, b, {
    pts: a.pts + b.pts,
    ast: a.ast + b.ast,
    // ...
  });

const buildStatsObject = reults => ({
  ppg: results.pts / games.length,
  // ...
});

const results = buildStatsObject(games.reduce(tallyGames));
```

Alternatively, you can build your stats object, with all values set to `0` (or some zeroed-out value), and include it as the second argument to reduce...
...but then `prev` is always your year stats, and not an actual game, so you have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce isnt the most appropriate way of calculating this since you are going to need to maintain running totals in order to perform the calculations that i am guessing you are trying to do.

You *could* compute the running total every iteration to calculate the new but that is very ugly and is prone to getting floating point rounding errors. By adding some running total properties you can calculate the new values properly, after fixing some bad variable names.

```js
games = [{
    game_id: 21700002,
    team_id: 1610612745,
    player_id: 201935,
    opponent_id: 1610612744,
    period: 'f',
    season: '2017',
    min: '36:24',
    fgm: 10,
    fga: 23,
    fg3m: 4,
    fg3a: 9,
    ftm: 3,
    fta: 4,
    oreb: 1,
    dreb: 5,
    ast: 10,
    blk: 0,
    stl: '1',
    to: 3,
    pf: 2,
    pts: 27,
    plus_minus: 1
  },
  {
    game_id: 21700002,
    team_id: 1610612745,
    player_id: 201935,
    opponent_id: 1610612744,
    period: 'f',
    season: '2017',
    min: '36:24',
    fgm: 10,
    fga: 23,
    fg3m: 4,
    fg3a: 9,
    ftm: 3,
    fta: 4,
    oreb: 1,
    dreb: 5,
    ast: 10,
    blk: 0,
    stl: '1',
    to: 3,
    pf: 2,
    pts: 27,
    plus_minus: 1
  },
  {
    game_id: 21700002,
    team_id: 1610612745,
    player_id: 201935,
    opponent_id: 1610612744,
    period: 'f',
    season: '2017',
    min: '36:24',
    fgm: 10,
    fga: 23,
    fg3m: 4,
    fg3a: 9,
    ftm: 3,
    fta: 4,
    oreb: 1,
    dreb: 5,
    ast: 10,
    blk: 0,
    stl: '1',
    to: 3,
    pf: 2,
    pts: 27,
    plus_minus: 1
  }
]



totalGames = games.length

var stats = games.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  var tpts = (prev.tpts + curr.pts)
  var tast = (prev.tast + curr.ast)
  var treb = (prev.treb + curr.oreb + curr.dreb)
  var tfga = (prev.tfga + curr.fga)
  var tfgm = (prev.tfgm + curr.fgm)
  var tfg3a = (prev.tfg3a + curr.fg3a)
  var tfg3m = (prev.tfg3m + curr.fg3m)
  return {
    tpts: tpts,
    tast: tast,
    treb: treb,
    tfga: tfga,
    tfgm: tfgm,
    tfg3a: tfg3a,
    tfg3m: tfg3m,
    ppg: tpts / totalGames,
    apg: tast / totalGames,
    rpg: treb / totalGames,
    fgp: (tfgm / tfga) * 100,
    fg3p: (tfg3m / tfg3a) * 100
  }

}, {tpts: 0, tast: 0, treb: 0, tfga: 0, tfgm: 0, tfg3a: 0, tfg3m: 0, ppg: 0, apg: 0, rpg: 0, fgp: 0, fg3p: 0});


console.log(stats);
```